# ClassCastException error ( Object and Vector )

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I am working with LWUIT List. Here is how the List is created :

```
db = new ClientDB();
listclient = db.listClient();
tModel = new ListSource(listclient);
renderer = new CListCell(true, new String[]{"", "", "Encours : ", "Impayés : "});
tList = new CList(tModel, renderer);

public Vector listClient()
    {
        try
        {
            filter = new Filter("");
            comparator = new Comparator();
            enumRec = this.enumerateRecords(filter, comparator);
            while(enumRec.hasNextElement())
            {
                id = enumRec.nextRecordId();
                recIDs.addElement(new Integer(id));
                bData = this.getRecord(id);
                client = new Client(bData);
                if (!innerResultat.isEmpty())
                {
                    innerResultat.removeAllElements();
                }
                innerResultat.addElement(new String(client.getIdclient()));
                innerResultat.addElement(new String(client.getCin()));
                innerResultat.addElement(new String(client.getNoms()));
                innerResultat.addElement(new String(client.getEncours()));
                innerResultat.addElement(new String(client.getImpayes()));
                resultat.addElement(innerResultat);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultat;
    }
public class ListSource extends DefaultListModel {

    public ListSource(Vector valeur)
    {
        super(valeur);
    }
    public int getListIDs(int ligneSelected)
    {
        return ligneSelected;
    }
}
public class CListCell extends Container implements ListCellRenderer {

    private boolean isPhotoDisplayed;

    private BorderLayout photoLayout = new BorderLayout();
    private BoxLayout yLayout = new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    private Vector vLabels = new Vector();
    private Label pic = new Label("");
    private Container cnt;

    private Font fontLibelle = (MenuPrincipalForm.r).getFont("FontTextFieldBold");

    private Label focus = new Label("");

    public CListCell(boolean displayPhoto, String[] libelles)
    {
        isPhotoDisplayed = displayPhoto;
        this.getSelectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        this.getUnselectedStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (displayPhoto)
        {
            setLayout(photoLayout);
            addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, pic);
        }
        else
        {
            setLayout(yLayout);
        }
        cnt = new Container(yLayout);
        for (int i=0;i<libelles.length;i++)
        {
            vLabels.addElement(new Label(libelles[i]));
            ((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
            ((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).getStyle().setFont(fontLibelle);
            cnt.addComponent(((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)));
        }
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);
        focus.getStyle().setBgTransparency(100);
    }
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)
    {
        Vector reelData = new Vector();
        if (value != null && (value instanceof Vector))
        {
            if (((Vector)value).isEmpty())
            {
                if (isPhotoDisplayed)
                    pic.setIcon(null);
                for (int i=0; i<vLabels.size(); i++)
                    ((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).setText(((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).getText().concat("-"));
            }
            else
            {
                reelData = (Vector)((Vector)value).elementAt(index);
                for (int i=0; i<vLabels.size(); i++)
                    ((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).setText(((Label)vLabels.elementAt(i)).getText().concat(String.valueOf(reelData.elementAt(i+1))));
                pic.setIcon(null);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list)
    {
        return focus;
    }
}
public class CList extends List {
    public CList(ListSource model, CListCell renderer)
    {
        setModel(model);
        setListCellRenderer(renderer);
        setItemGap(0);
        setFixedSelection(List.FIXED_NONE_CYCLIC);
    }
}
```

And in the `getListCellRendererComponent` method of the `ListCellRenderer` the `value` parameter causes me the problem. Its type is `Object` in the Javadoc , and the real datatype of it in my application is `Vector`, it is a Vector of Vector ( a Vector whose elements are Vector).

My problem is that I get the `ClassCastException` error in runtime , and the stack error shows that the `getListCellRendererComponent` method caused the error.

So how to work with Object and Vector ?

Stack error is :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:   0
 - view.CListCell.getListCellRendererComponent(), bci=112
 - com.sun.lwuit.plaf.DefaultLookAndFeel.getListPreferredSize(), bci=218
 - com.sun.lwuit.List.calcPreferredSize(), bci=7
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.preferredSize(), bci=28
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredSize(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredH(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.layouts.FlowLayout.getPreferredSize(), bci=70
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.calcPreferredSize(), bci=5
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.preferredSize(), bci=28
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredSize(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredH(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout.getPreferredSize(), bci=38
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.calcPreferredSize(), bci=5
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.preferredSize(), bci=28
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredSize(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getPreferredH(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.layouts.FlowLayout.getPreferredSize(), bci=70
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.calcPreferredSize(), bci=5
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.calcScrollSize(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getScrollDimension(), bci=23
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.isScrollableY(), bci=8
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.getSideGap(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.layouts.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(), bci=18
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.doLayout(), bci=5
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.layoutContainer(), bci=13
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.doLayout(), bci=37
 - com.sun.lwuit.Container.layoutContainer(), bci=13
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.initFocused(), bci=20
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.show(), bci=25
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.show(), bci=2
 - controler.SmartPhoneBanking.displayScreen(), bci=19
 - view.MenuPrincipalForm.actionPerformed(), bci=56
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(), bci=19
 - com.sun.lwuit.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(), bci=89
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.fireActionEvent(), bci=70
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.released(), bci=17
 - com.sun.lwuit.Button.pointerReleased(), bci=1
 - com.sun.lwuit.Form.pointerReleased(), bci=93
 - com.sun.lwuit.Component.pointerReleased(), bci=7
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.handleEvent(), bci=125
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.edtLoopImpl(), bci=115
 - com.sun.lwuit.Display.mainEDTLoop(), bci=198
 - com.sun.lwuit.RunnableWrapper.run(), bci=242
 - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=11
```

Comment: You are still supressing the essential part of the exception telling you which object it should've been. Post the actual stack trace.

Comment: what `Object` you are passing on the `List`?

Comment: @bharath : it is the Vector of Vector which I pass to the List as its datasource model.

Comment: Can you show your code how to pass the values in the List?

Comment: Why is there a java-me tag on that question? Do you execute this code in JavaME?

Comment: @jmg Yes I execute this code in JavaME

Comment: Can you comment the `else` part and run the application?

Comment: I have removed the Vector inside the outer Vector , instead I put a String and the problem has not raised any more.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's a good idea to check whether cast are possible or not. In your case you seem to get some object which is not a Vector.

```
if (value != null && value instanceof Vector) {
    Vector vector = (Vector) value;

    ... your body with vector instead of value
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Man I didn't get a Vector!");
}
```

Did you consider using generic types?

Comment: There is something very strange : I wrote this code : `if (value != null && (value instanceof Vector))` before the cast and the application enters the `if` bloc ( I wrote a System.out.println ). But when entering the `if` block then the ClassCastException is raised ! I printed the vector's number of elements and it shows 3. So what to do ?

Comment: Then your diagnosis of the source of the exception is wrong. Could you post your modified code and the complete stack trace?

Comment: Do you use any framework which do modify byte code of classes?

Comment: I do not know. What I know is that I have downloaded Sun Java ME Platform SDK 3.0 and the Oracle JDK for windows

Comment: java me has no generics it's based on JDK 1.3 (see egg in wikipedia)